# Unable to maintain the textsize in Android Textview

Tags: android, textview

In my app, there is a textview. The textview is populated with the data from the DB. The following is the XML of the textview

```
            android:id="@+id/ViewMessageOne"               
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"

            />
```

The following is the lines of code to populate the data in the textview from DB

```
final TextView ViewMessageOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewMessageOne);
ViewMessageOne.setText(Html.fromHtml(getMessages("MSG_ONE")+  "<br>" + "<small>" + getTimeStamp("MSG_ONE") + "</small>"));
```

When the data from DB is populated, the text size in the screen is small and is not taking the XML value. I checked this by increasing the size of the textview text. But it is not taking the text size from the XML. Can anyone guide me as how to get the value of the text size value from the XML and hence implement it using JAVA code. Thanks

Comment: remove  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" and try

Answer (score 0):

you have follow line in your code:

```
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

which probably overrides your custom textsize
remove that line and try again

Edit: to set text size programmatically:

```
   viewMessageOne.setTextSize(16)
```

Comment: Thanks.I did that. But still the issue persists. Is there a way to read the textsize from the XML and reinforce it in Activity code.

Comment: see edit, you can go a long way with google on questions like this, they have been asked time and time again

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
android:layout_height="45dp"
```

to this

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```